# CSS: Different Elements Have The Same Transition, But Does Not Fade-in Or Fade-out The Same Way

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, transition, fade

I am making a dropdown menu, which is supposed to fade in and fade out when you hover over it. All the elements have the same transition, but the first tab which is always visible looks different when hovering over it. If you look closely when hovering over the dropdown, you can see a little difference between the two elements.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a9b83786/

HTML:

```
    <div class="nav">
    <!--.xX~Dropdown~Xx.-->
    <div class="navChild navDropdown">
        <!--Dropdown parent-->
        <div class="navTab navTabDropdownParent">
            Units
        </div>
        <!--Dropdown item-->
        <a href="#" class="navTab navTabDropdownItem">
            Length [M]
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
  :root{
  /*Colors*/
  --Normal-Color: #24AAB8;
  --Hover-Color: #26C2A5;
  --Active-Color: #26C24D;

  /*Lengths*/
  --Nav-Height: 60px;

  /*Multiplier*/
  --NavTab-Width-Multiplier: 2;
}
/*Navigation Tabs*/
/*Nav tabs in general*/
.navChild {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.navDropdown:hover .navTabDropdownParent {
  background-color: var(--Normal-Color)
}
.navDropdown:hover .navTabDropdownItem {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navDropdown {
  height: var(--Nav-Height);
}
.navDropdown:hover {
  height: auto;
}



/* MAIN TRANSITION CODE */
.navTab {
  height: var(--Nav-Height);
  width: calc(var(--NavTab-Width-Multiplier) * var(--Nav-Height));
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--Nav-Height);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.2s linear; /* First transition */
}
.navChild:hover .navTab {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.2s linear; /* Second transition */
}





/*Buttons*/
.navTabButton:hover {
  background-color: var(--Hover-Color);
}
.navTabButton:active {
  background-color: var(--Active-Color);
}
/*Dropdown*/
.navTabDropdownItem:hover {
  background-color: var(--Hover-Color);
}
.navTabDropdownItem:active {
  background-color: var(--Active-Color);
}
.navTabDropdownItem{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: var(--Normal-Color);
}
```

(Check JSFiddle for updates)

Comment: looked closely and didn't see the difference ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good in some browsers (i.a. Firefox). According to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#interpolated-types), both background color and transparency transitions, in your case, should calculate to the same interpolated values. 
So I think this is a bug. You can easily work around this by replacing opacity change with change in background color and text color: https://jsfiddle.net/hcphs3ey/.

```
.navTabDropdownItem{
   visibility: hidden;
   color:transparent;
   background-color: white;
}
.navDropdown:hover .navTabDropdownItem {
   visibility: visible;
   background-color: var(--Normal-Color);
   color:black;
}
```

Comment: The transition works perfectly fine now, but the hovering colour has disappeared in the dropdown menu.

Comment: You need to give the hovering background priority. I updated the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/hcphs3ey/1/